# My code takes up 2000MB+ to run, no idea why

Tags: java, processing

Yea so for some reason when I run my code it requires a bit over 2GB to run. It probably has something to due with a picture being drawn a lot of times or something, but I'm not sure.
If someone could explain to me why this is happening, I'd be very grateful!

```
import gifAnimation.*; //imports functions from the Gif Animation library
PImage Animation, BackButton, ProgrammingIMG, CommunicationIMG, GamedevIMG, GraphicsIMG, VideoIMG, SoundIMG, Medialogy;
boolean ProgrammingClick, CommunicationClick, GamedevClick, GraphicsClick, VideoDevClick, SoundDevClick, MedialogyClick = false;
int stage; //creates a integer variable called stage.
Gif Frontpage; 


void setup() { //we load all the images beforehand to reduce load time.
  size(1415, 1000);  //size of window
  frameRate(100); //framerate of the gifs
  smooth(); //anti-aliased edges and smoother images when resized.
  BackButton = loadImage("Go_back_button.png"); 
  GamedevIMG = loadImage("1_Game_development.jpg");
  ProgrammingIMG = loadImage("2_Programming.jpg");
  VideoIMG = loadImage("3_Video_production.jpg");
  SoundIMG = loadImage("4_Sound_and_music_computing.jpg");
  CommunicationIMG = loadImage("5_communication.jpg");
  GraphicsIMG = loadImage("6_graphic_design.jpg");
  Medialogy = loadImage("7_medialogy.jpg");
  Frontpage = new Gif(this,"0_BigGif.gif");


  Frontpage. loop(); //makes the gif loop.
  stage = 1; //The app starts in stage 1
}

void draw() {

   if(SoundDevClick==true && stage==1){ //sound
    stage=3; 
    image(SoundIMG, 0, 0, width, height);
    image(BackButton,15,930);  
  }

  else if(MedialogyClick==true && stage==1){ //If the boolean (MedialogyClick) is true, and we are in stage one, we will go to stage 2.
     stage=2;
     image(Medialogy, 0, 0, width, height);
     image(BackButton,15,930);
   }

   else if(ProgrammingClick==true && stage==1){ //programming
    stage=4;
    image(ProgrammingIMG, 0, 0, width, height);
    image(BackButton,15,930);
  }
   else if(GamedevClick==true && stage==1){ //gamedev
    stage=5;
    image(GamedevIMG, 0, 0, width, height);
    image(BackButton,15,930);
  }
   else if(GraphicsClick==true && stage==1){ //graphics
    stage=6;
    image(GraphicsIMG, 0, 0, width, height);
    image(BackButton,15,930);

  }
   else if(VideoDevClick==true && stage==1){ //videodev
    stage=7;
    image(VideoIMG, 0, 0, width, height);
    image(BackButton,15,930);
  }
   else if(CommunicationClick==true && stage==1){ //communication
    stage=8;
    image(CommunicationIMG, 0, 0, width, height);
    image(BackButton,15,930);
  }

 else if(stage==1){ //if the program is in stage 1, the main page will be shown.
  image(Frontpage, 0,0, width, height);
  }



  else if(SoundDevClick==false){ //If the boolean SoundDevClick is false, stage 1 will be called, and we will now be in stage 1. 
    stage=1;
  }

 else if(GamedevClick==false){
    stage=1;
  }
  else if(GraphicsClick==false){
    stage=1;
  }
  else if(CommunicationClick==false){
    stage=1;
  }
  else if(ProgrammingClick==false){
    stage=1;
  }
  else if(MedialogyClick==false){
    stage=1;
  }
  else if(VideoDevClick==false){
    stage=1;
  }



}


void mousePressed() { //if the mouse is pressed it will state Clicked as true, therefore opening the image "Open.png", but only if the "if" statement is true.



 if (mouseX>300 && mouseX<550 && mouseY>230 && mouseY<450 && mouseButton == LEFT && stage ==1) { //If the mouse is within the defined parameters, and the left mousebutton is pressed, SoundDevClick will be set as true.
    SoundDevClick=true; //Music
 } 

 if (mouseX>700 && mouseX<930 && mouseY>745 && mouseY<980 && mouseButton == LEFT && stage ==1) { //GameDev
    GamedevClick=true;
 } 

 if (mouseX>1000 && mouseX<1320 && mouseY>320 && mouseY<600 && mouseButton == LEFT && stage ==1) { //Graphics
    GraphicsClick=true;
 } 

 if (mouseX>40 && mouseX<270 && mouseY>355 && mouseY<790 && mouseButton == LEFT && stage ==1) { //Video Dev
    VideoDevClick=true;
 } 

 if (mouseX>540 && mouseX<960 && mouseY>190 && mouseY<470 && mouseButton == LEFT && stage ==1) { //Communication
    CommunicationClick=true;
 } 

 if (mouseX>400 && mouseX<650 && mouseY>500 && mouseY<790 && mouseButton == LEFT && stage ==1) { //Programming
    ProgrammingClick=true;
 } 

 if (mouseX>470 && mouseX<950 && mouseY>15 && mouseY<115 && mouseButton == LEFT && stage ==1) { //Medialogy
    MedialogyClick=true;
 }

 else if (mouseX>0 && mouseX<240 && mouseY>910 && mouseY<1000 && mouseButton == LEFT) { //If left mousebutton is pressed within parameters, it will set following booleans as false (Resulting in going back to stage 1).

    SoundDevClick=false;
    GamedevClick=false;
    GraphicsClick=false;
    CommunicationClick=false;
    ProgrammingClick=false;
    MedialogyClick=false;
    VideoDevClick=false;
 } 



}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that the code should be at least compilable (if it is not about compiler errors). Also it's difficult to help you as we don'T know your images (or at least the size of it).

Comment: I hate questions that start with "Yea so" or "OK". Public writing is different from "thought dump."

Comment: While I'm at it, any time I see `x==true` or `y==false` I think "code smell". What you mean is `x` or `!y`.

Comment: Try to give us a clear code with a clear description. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask will you a good guidance how to ask a good question

Answer (score 0):

try to use **[requestImage](http://www.processing.org/reference/requestImage_.html)** instead of **loadImage**. 
Maybe the images you are using is of large size.